# What's the most concise way to "forward" method calls on a Python object?

Tags: python, oop

I'm writing some report generation code, where a class `CoverageReporter` is doing all of the heavy lifting, with just a few attributes changing between different instances of `CoverageReporter`. Let's say we want to alias

```py
SubsystemCoverageReporter(*args, **kwargs)
```

to

```py
CoverageReporter('subsystem', *args, **kwargs)
```

in a concise way. Currently, I accomplish it like so:

```py
class SubsystemCoverageReporter(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.reporter = CoverageReporter('subsystem', *args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.reporter, name)
```

Another one, subsystem 2, has almost *exactly* the same boilerplate, eg:

```py
class SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.reporter = CoverageReporter('subsystem2', *args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.reporter, name)
```

Is there a more concise + Pythonic way to express this? I'd prefer not to rely on inheritance, but if there's no better ways I'm open to that.

Comment: You should have a base class `SubsystemCoverageReporterBase` which defines the `__getattr__` and then have `SubsystemCoverageReporter` and `SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter` inherit that base class

Comment: Are there any other things that you change in `SubsystemCoverageReporter`? Any extra methods/attributes etc, or is it just `CoverageReporter` with first arg `subsystem`?

Comment: Or better yet, have the `SubsystemCoverageReporter ` classes extend the `CoverageReporter` and override the `__init__()` method

Comment: @theo-brown for now, you can assume there's only one or a few attributes like `'subsystem'`, and all of the important bits living in `CoverageReporter`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I'd like to avoid inheritance, if possible!

Comment: Is there a reason you'd like to avoid inheritance? That is the most concise + pythonic way IMO

Comment: Is there a reason for avoiding inheritance? The thing that gets round the boilerplate you describe is defining a base class, that's kind of the point of OOP.

Comment: The main reason is to prevent multiple inheritance down the line, but if there's not another way (decorator?), inheritance will work just fine!

Comment: What is wrong with what you have already? Seems pretty concise, and more importantly, seems pretty obvious what it's doing because it is using idiomatic approaches, i.e. **it is very pythonic**. "terse" != Pythonic

Comment: that's a good point @juanpa.arrivillaga! The main reason I asked this question is probably an inherent adherence to D.R.Y (which as we know can sometimes lead one to bad abstractions)

Comment: @theo-brown I mean, no. The "point" of OOP is not to write classes and make inheritance hierarchies. Indeed, inheritance has fallen out of fashion in a lot of places. Of course, this *may* be a case where it is the best solution, but then again, the proxying technique the OP is showing is also a common solution in Python

Comment: @ijustlovemath ok, I mean, usually the simplest way to accomplish DRY is to wrap your code in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you had your class `CoverageReporter` like so:

```
class CoverageReporter:
    def __init__(self, _type, _name):
        self.type = _type
        self.name = _name
        
    def do_something(self):
        print(f"{self.type}:{self.name} did something")
        
    def do_something_else(self):
        print(f"{self.type}:{self.name} did something else")
```

You could define a function which creates the `CoverageReporter` and returns that object.

```
def SubsystemCoverageReporter(*args, **kwargs):
    return CoverageReporter('subsystem', *args, **kwargs)


def SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter(*args, **kwargs):
    return CoverageReporter('subsystem2', *args, **kwargs)

s1 = SubsystemCoverageReporter("Foo")
s2 = SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter("Bar")

s1.do_something()         # subsystem:Foo did something
s2.do_something_else()    # subsystem2:Bar did something else
```

Note that this isn't exactly equivalent to what you have, since `SubsystemCoverageReporter` isn't a *class*, so you won't be able to inherit it. If you want that option available, then off the top of my head I think inheritance is the best solution you have.

```
class SubsystemCoverageReporter(CoverageReporter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__('subsystem', *args, **kwargs)
        
class SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter(CoverageReporter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__('subsystem2', *args, **kwargs)

s1 = SubsystemCoverageReporter("Foo")
s2 = SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter("Bar")

s1.do_something()         # subsystem:Foo did something
s2.do_something_else()    # subsystem2:Bar did something else
```

Comment: using a function like a class constructor is pretty clever! I'll definitely look into this!

Comment: @theo-brown :) Your answer didn't really do what OP wanted because passing `subsystem_name` to `new_subsystemcoveragereporter()` is the exact same as passing it to `CoverageReporter()`

Comment: It's poor styling to use the same case for classes and functions; I'd recommend changing the name of the functions so that they don't look like classes (e.g. `new_subsystemcoveragereporter()`

Comment: A lack of inheritance is actually a *feature* in my mind. And while it may be poor style generally, mimicking the API of a class while not allowing all aspects of a class is an occasionally useful restriction.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid repeating yourself, use the *same solution you always would*, wrap the repeated code in a function and parameterize the parts that can change:

```
def make_klass(subsystem):
    class SubsystemCoverageReporter(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.reporter = CoverageReporter(subsystem, *args, **kwargs)
    
        def __getattr__(self, name):
            return getattr(self.reporter, name)
    return SubsystemCoverageReporter


SubsystemCoverageReporter = make_klass("subsystem")
SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter = make_klass("subsystem2")
```

Note, the classes you create will have the same value for their `__name__` attribute. That is *hopefully* not important, but you can get around it, e.g.:

SubsystemCoverageReporter.**name** = "SubsystemCoverageReporter"
SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter.**name** = "SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter"

Although that is ugly.

You could use the `type` constructor directly, or if metaclasses are an issue, use `types.new_class` instead and it will handle it correctly. But in the simplest case,

```
def make_klass(name, subsystem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.reporter = CoverageReporter(subsystem, *args, **kwargs)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.reporter, name)
    klass = type(name, (object,), dict(__init__=__init__, __getattr__=__getattr__))
    return klass

SubsystemCoverageReporter = make_klass("SubsystemCoverageReporter", "subsystem")
SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter = make_klass("SubsystemTwoCoverageReporter", "subsytem2")
```

Although note, you are repeating yourself here a little.

But again, normally you shouldn't care about the `__name__` attribute